# CALayer dealloc crash in secondary thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, crash, calayer

I received the following crashlog, and I'm having some trouble figuring out in what part of my app its happening.

```
Hardware Model:      iPad2,4
Process:         MYAPP [129]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/FC5BD37F-838A-4CDD-8158-5A2B6F34C3AB/MYAPP.app/MYAPP
Identifier:      com.myapp
Version:         4.0
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x8
Crashed Thread:  6

Thread 0:
0   libz.1.dylib                        0x38b9a3c8 _zError + 1159
1   ImageIO                             0x2e9755b9 <redacted> + 308
2   ImageIO                             0x2e973155 <redacted> + 2400
3   ImageIO                             0x2e97227f <redacted> + 542
4   CoreGraphics                        0x2dcaf44d _CGImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetWithOptions + 136
5   QuartzCore                          0x300e9105 <redacted> + 684
6   QuartzCore                          0x300e85af <redacted> + 290
7   QuartzCore                          0x300e8e47 <redacted> + 18
8   QuartzCore                          0x300bd201 <redacted> + 384
9   QuartzCore                          0x300bc6e7 <redacted> + 238
10  QuartzCore                          0x300bc4ef <redacted> + 314
11  QuartzCore                          0x300b621d <redacted> + 56
12  CoreFoundation                      0x2dbf32a5 <redacted> + 20
13  CoreFoundation                      0x2dbf0c49 <redacted> + 284
14  CoreFoundation                      0x2dbf0f8b <redacted> + 730
15  CoreFoundation                      0x2db5bf0f _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
16  CoreFoundation                      0x2db5bcf3 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
17  GraphicsServices                    0x32a55663 _GSEventRunModal + 138
18  UIKit                               0x304a716d _UIApplicationMain + 1136
19  MYAPP                           0x000b7177 __mh_execute_header + 29047
20  libdyld.dylib                       0x38c19ab7 <redacted> + 2

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38cbc808 _kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x38bfde03 <redacted> + 38

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38ccfc70 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36a98 _start_wqthread + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38ccfc70 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36a98 _start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38cbca58 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2dbf289b <redacted> + 154
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2dbf0fc1 <redacted> + 784
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2db5bf0f _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2db5bcf3 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
5   Foundation                          0x2e59b087 +[NSURLConnection _resourceLoadLoop:] + 318
6   Foundation                          0x2e610a5f <redacted> + 1062
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d38919 <redacted> + 140
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d3888b __pthread_start + 102
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36aa4 _thread_start + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38ccfc70 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36a98 _start_wqthread + 8

Thread 6 Crashed:
0   QuartzCore                          0x300c0376 <redacted> + 5
1   QuartzCore                          0x300bfe63 <redacted> + 142
2   QuartzCore                          0x300bfb13 -[CALayer dealloc] + 142
3   QuartzCore                          0x300bf881 <redacted> + 136
4   QuartzCore                          0x300bc547 <redacted> + 402
5   QuartzCore                          0x3011dfa1 <redacted> + 576
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x38bfbad7 <redacted> + 222
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x38bfbd29 <redacted> + 56
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36bd3 __pthread_wqthread + 298
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36a98 _start_wqthread + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38cbca58 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2dbf289b <redacted> + 154
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2dbf0fc1 <redacted> + 784
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2db5bf0f _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2db5bcf3 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
5   WebCore                             0x3603011b <redacted> + 418
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d38919 <redacted> + 140
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d3888b __pthread_start + 102
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36aa4 _thread_start + 8

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38cbca58 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2dbf289b <redacted> + 154
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2dbf0fc1 <redacted> + 784
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2db5bf0f _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2db5bcf3 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
5   Foundation                          0x2e54e1eb -[NSRunLoop runMode:beforeDate:] + 254
6   Foundation                          0x2e59f0a1 -[NSRunLoop run] + 80
7   MYAPP                           0x002c533d +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] + 80
8   Foundation                          0x2e610a5f <redacted> + 1062
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d38919 <redacted> + 140
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d3888b __pthread_start + 102
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36aa4 _thread_start + 8

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38ccf434 ___select + 20
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d38919 <redacted> + 140
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d3888b __pthread_start + 102
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36aa4 _thread_start + 8

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38ccef2c ___psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d38d65 _pthread_cond_wait + 40
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x2eb88ee9 <redacted> + 208
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x2eb8653b <redacted> + 14
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d38919 <redacted> + 140
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d3888b __pthread_start + 102
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36aa4 _thread_start + 8

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38ccef2c ___psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d38d65 _pthread_cond_wait + 40
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x2ed2440b <redacted> + 78
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x2ed24465 <redacted> + 52
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x2eb8653b <redacted> + 14
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d38919 <redacted> + 140
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d3888b __pthread_start + 102
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36aa4 _thread_start + 8

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38cbca58 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2dbf289b <redacted> + 154
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2dbf0fc1 <redacted> + 784
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2db5bf0f _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2db5bcf3 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
5   WebCore                             0x36078b17 <redacted> + 254
6   JavaScriptCore                      0x2eb8653b <redacted> + 14
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d38919 <redacted> + 140
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d3888b __pthread_start + 102
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36aa4 _thread_start + 8

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38ccef2c ___psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d38d65 _pthread_cond_wait + 40
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x2eb88ee9 <redacted> + 208
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x2eb8653b <redacted> + 14
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d38919 <redacted> + 140
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d3888b __pthread_start + 102
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36aa4 _thread_start + 8

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38ccef2c ___psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d38d65 _pthread_cond_wait + 40
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x2ed2440b <redacted> + 78
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x2ed24465 <redacted> + 52
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x2eb8653b <redacted> + 14
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d38919 <redacted> + 140
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d3888b __pthread_start + 102
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36aa4 _thread_start + 8

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38ccfc70 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36a98 _start_wqthread + 8

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x38cbca58 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2dbf289b <redacted> + 154
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2dbf0fc1 <redacted> + 784
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2db5bf0f _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2db9fa03 _CFRunLoopRun + 98
5   CoreMotion                          0x2e2193ad _CLSF_thorntonUpdate_6x6 + 56957
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d38919 <redacted> + 140
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d3888b __pthread_start + 102
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38d36aa4 _thread_start + 8

Thread 6 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    pc: 0x300c0376     r7: 0x03389d68     sp: 0x03389d0c     r0: 0x00000000 
    r1: 0x16b1d800     r2: 0x00000002     r3: 0x300c435d     r4: 0x16b1d800 
    r5: 0x00000000     r6: 0x17a3e820     r8: 0x03389d20     r9: 0x17200020 
   r10: 0x39202310    r11: 0x00000000     ip: 0x3ac7ebc8     lr: 0x300c02ab 
  cpsr: 0x60000030
```

I noticed that there's a `-[CALayer dealloc]` call on the crashed thread, so I'm guessing that I accidentally called some UI update from a secondary thread.

So here are my questions: Am I right to assume the  problem is updating UI from a secondary thread? And if so, can this crashlog help me figure out where in my code the mistake is?

Comment: Why have you removed method names from the stack trace that are internal to Quartz and ImageIO?

Comment: I haven't removed the Quartz and ImageIO method names, I received the crash report from Flurry like this

Comment: Bizarre. Flurry should not be removing those. But anyway, CALayer can do asynchronous rendering, and often does. CALayer is not required to use the main thread for rendering. Your crash appears to be happening in zlib (compression), called by ImageIO when decompressing your image.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that can at least help me narrow down a lot my search